# Setting user/group restrictions in Windows 7 Home Premium

Tags: windows-7, administration

I'm have been requested to set user restrictions across 100+ computers running Windows 7 Home Premium.

I have done a bit of research and I have found that the user restrictions I'm able to set via the control panel are very limited.

In addition, the Group Policy Editor and the Local Users and Groups snap-in is not available for this addition of Windows.

Is there another way to setup user restrictions without the use of the the Group Policy Editor and the Local Users and Groups snap-in?

What are my options?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this via the *registry editor*.´ You can save time by creating a script that does it for you.

This reference([Group Policy Registry Table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms815238.aspx)) can help you.

Comment: Is there currently any script that does this? I was searching for such a solution... In addition, would tampering with the registry keys void my Microsoft license? What are the pros and cons of editing the registry to do this?

Answer (score 0):

For my personal computer, I use this: http://codemink.com/download-group-policy-editor-for-windows-7-home-premium/

But on 100+ Computers? Maybe not.
 I think the easiest way to do all of those system changes would be through the registry. You'd be able to create a .reg file for all the changes you want, then use said file on every computer.

A bit tedious, I must admit, but I think it'd get the job done.

Comment: I tried that download on one of the computers, but what use is the Group Policy Editor if I can't import the Local Users and Groups snap-in and actually assign any of these polices to a user or a group? Am I missing something?

Comment: Er, the link seems broken, and I don't see anything else concrete in this answer.